# Save Last generated random numbers in memory java Web App

Tags: java, singleton

I'm using random numbers to generate numbers for lottery.
But when i try to use Java's random generator

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(totalsize);
```

This does not generate pure random numbers even after using the currentTimeMillis as seed.
So I'm considering that I should save the previous random numbers , and generate  the new random number after comparing with the old ones.
These random numbers are not generated in a loop. So they cannot be compared unless stored in memory or database.

To save the previous random numbers, I'm thinking of few options

-Either save them using Singleton (not sure how I would do it and how good the solution is)

-Or to save the values in database

-Third which I don't want to implement is to use a memcache or something because the date is only 20 numbers that i have to save, so its an overkill and out of option because of the server's memory limitation.

Should i use Singleton or Database to store this temporary data .
IF Singleton, then how?

My requirement is to save 10 Lists(1 for each of 10 different lottery types) saving 2 previous random values in them

EDIT: Its a JAVA Web App running on tomcat. So simply maintaining a list is not possible .
Everytime a client hits the servlet,a random number is generated. So i need to send a random number from server, which is not repeated with the previous two values.

Comment: Stock answer #3: Don't seed the RNG inside your loop. My guess is that you're creating a new Random object for each number, which is exactly the wrong thing to do. Create the object ONCE, at the start of your program, and then ONLY call nextInt() inside the loop.

Comment: Can you post your code?
What do you mean by "impure" random numbers?

Comment: Also, do you mind telling me where I buy a lottery ticket for this lottery?  Knowing the approximate time at which the number will be generated (say, within a few weeks), and that the generator is seeded with a time really helps me in picking my numbers.  In summary, don't do that, for a real lottery anyway. Use SecureRandom which, if you give it a seed, just combines that with random seed taken from the hardware.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i missed to tell that its a Web App , so everytime there is request from the client a random number is generated. But with the Java random generator, some numbers are repeatedly generated. So i need to save them in memory or database, to compare and send a number again.

Comment: @Keith its a lottery thing, not a lottery ticket. I know by knowing the seed one can determine the random number that will be generated. Doesn't involve winning cash. hehe

Comment: Well of course numbers might be repeated--they wouldn't be random if they weren't. You need to decide what you really want here, and describe it more clearly.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to maintain the last two random numbers being sent in memory. Should i use Singleton or database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want exactly though Since you only storing the values temporarily why not store the values in arraylists as you say its part of the requirement to have 10 lists,so why not use them then compare the 2nd random numbers u generated with the numbers in the list and so on.

Eg

```
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

    int count=10;
    int random =randomGenerator.nextInt(totalsize);
    While(count>0)
    {
     if(list1.contains(random))
       continue;
      else
      { 
       list1.add(random );    
        --count;
      }
    }
```

you have a list with 10 different number,
create another list, generate a number ,check if the number is in the previous list if not add to current list

I'm not if this is what you wanna do but pretty much what I can gather from info you provided and description of your problem isn't much clearer to me, so hope I helped ;)
Oh yea if you must then once all done you save all data in your database

Comment: Its a webapp, so everytime a client hits the servlet,a random number is generated. So i need to send a random number from server, which is not repeated with the previous two values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want decent random numbers, you should simply use [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) instead of `Random` ... and let it seed itself from a decent system-level source of entropy.

Comparing numbers from a "poor" random number source against previously generated numbers is not going to fix the problem.  The numbers will still be biased and/or predictable.

---

On the other hand, if your real aim is to generate 3 distinct numbers<sup>1</sup>, I'd suggest using either in a client-side browser cookie, or in a server-side session object to implement the duplicate elimination.  In the latter case, there is probably no need to persist the information.  If the user takes too long to retrieve all 3 numbers ... too bad.

<sup>1 - Strictly, this is not a sequence of random numbers, since the elimination of duplicates introduces an element of non-randomness.</sup>

Comment: Its a webapp, so everytime a client hits the servlet,a random number is generated. So i need to send a random number from server, which is not repeated with the previous two values.

Comment: Then it is not a random number.  A true random number *could* repeat.

Comment: i know thats why i need to maintain the last few values in memory so that i dont send out same values one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of how sessions (user specific in memory stores) work on tomcat (or any application serever)?  One possibility is store the previously generated numbers (it sounds like a max of 20 numbers) in each user's session:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    //
    // get the previous number map from the session.
    //
    Map<String, List<Integer>> previousNumberMap = (Map<String, List<Integer>>) session.getAttribute("previousNumberMap");
    if (previousNumberMap == null) {
        previousNumberMap = new HashMap<>();
        session.setAttribute("previousNumberMap", previousNumberMap);
    }

    //
    // get the previous numbers for lottery type B
    //
    List<Integer> previousNumbersList = previousNumberMap.get("lotteryTypeB");

    //
    // find a new number that isn't in the list of previous numbers.
    //
    int currentNumber = random.nextInt();
    while (previousNumbersList.contains(currentNumber)) {
        currentNumber = random.nextInt();  // new random number
    }

    //
    // Add the new number to the list of previous values
    //
    previousNumbersList.add(currentNumber);
```